# Unexpected End Of Stream error in reading xml data with InputStream of HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button submit;
EditText textBox;

String xmlRequest = "<Request><Merchant_Number>111111111111</Merchant_Number><Terminal_ID>001</Terminal_ID><Action_Code>05</Action_Code><Trans_Type>N</Trans_Type><POS_Entry_Mode>S</POS_Entry_Mode><Track_Data2>71019520xxxxxx=</Track_Data2></Request>";

String domain = "www.somedomain.com/gateway.php";
String domainForSocket = "https://" + domain;
URL a;
String sucess = "sucess";
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;
String header;
String writeData; // data which will be sent to server

byte[] outputInBytes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    writeData = xmlRequest;
    textBox.setText(writeData);

    // creating thread to run on background for network connection

    final Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                a = new URL(domainForSocket);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                outputInBytes = xmlRequest.getBytes("UTF-8");

                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) a.openConnection();
                urlConnection
                        .setFixedLengthStreamingMode(outputInBytes.length);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""
                        + outputInBytes.length);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language",
                        "en-US");

                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Log.v(sucess, "connectio open");

            try {

                OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

                out.write(outputInBytes, 0, outputInBytes.length);
                out.close();

                // Send request

                Log.v(sucess, "output sent");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Output Error", "error in sending data to server");
            }

            try {

                InputStream a = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(a);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(read);

                String data = "";
                // Log.v("code execute", "i am here");
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuffer ab = new StringBuffer();
                Log.v("result", "if you dont see then no data");

                while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(data);
                    Log.v("data", data.toString());
                }

                a.close(); // closing input string


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Data Receiving Error",
                        "Error in receiving dat from server");
            }

            finally {
                // urlConnection.disconnect();
                try {

                    // mSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Socket close Error", "cant close socket");
                }
            }

            // sending output

        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                mThread.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });



}
```

Above is my complete source code for XML HTTP Request. I getting XML response from the server. But I am getting the below error in logcat whenever I send request to the server. Can anyone help me on this issue.
Any help will be appreaciated.

Here is the log:

```
02-17 11:09:33.684: W/System.err(6446): java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
02-17 11:09:33.689: W/System.err(6446):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:445)
02-17 11:09:33.690: W/System.err(6446):     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
```

Comment: please add complete stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I was not opening socket with android's inbuilt SSL socket library

```
javax.net.SocketFactory fact=SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
         socket=fact.createSocket(addr, port);
```

This two line code wasted my four precious days :(